# Get show.bs.collapse event only for parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a accordion panel(parent) inside another accordion panel(child). The parent keeps on collapsing every time I click on the child accordion.

```
function check () {
    $('div.icon-tab.in').collapse('hide');
}

$('#services-parent').on('show.bs.collapse',check);
```

Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3

Tab 1 = {Child-Tab-1 | Child-Tab-2 | Child-Tab-3}

Once I click on the Child-tab-1, the Tab 1 keeps on collapsing
I would like to only get the event of the parent, and not the child.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
$('[data-parent="services-parent"]').on('click', function() {
    $('div.icon-tab.in').collapse('hide');
    console.log("Icon Button Clicked!");
});
```